# When in his suit, how does Tony Stark control when others can hear him talking?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, iron-man, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, when Iron-Man and Captain America are fighting,

> The suit's AI tells Tony  that he can't match Cap in hand-to-hand combat. So Tony asks the suit to analyse his fighting style.

Cap and Iron-man were speaking shortly before and I was wondering, **how does Tony regulate when his voice can be heard outside of the suit?**

Comment: It would be logical for an intelligent suit to mute the comms. before it announces to the operator that the opponent can whup his ass! (It wouldn't be very 'intelligent' otherwise.)

Comment: It would have to be a tremendously intelligent suit to know to use speakers for "You know, I've been thinking, this has been fun and all, but maybe we could sit down and talk?" but not for "You know, I've been thinking, this has been fun and all, but let's enable hellfire missles and nuke this guy's butt."  The AIQ would have to wait long enough to evaluate the content of the entire sentence, which would introduce a weird and not-seen-on-screen delay between Tony talking and the suit passing it on.

Comment: I suspect he has some kind of Brain-Computer Interface onboard. Otherwise Jarvis would have to control the firing of his weapons and other things.

Comment: Eye-control; https://vimeo.com/65879807

Answer (score 2):

In the comics, after the events of Extremis, Tony has a telepathic connection to his technology as a result of modifying and "engineering" the virus to suit his needs. This link provides him with effective technomancy powers including some levels of silver age esq tech-precognition. This being said, Tony never contracts extremis during the events of Iron Man 3 in the MCU thus no silver age powers.

However, Tony can be seen in this same movie, experimenting with motion, retinal and gesture controls. Its feasible that a combination of minute body gestures (never visible from outside the suit) tone (which can be noticed in his dialogue) and retina tracking could be used to provide the split second switching between talking to Friday/Jarvis, radio communication, and local announcements.